# any code to fetch new scrape info for facebook share in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am running a php based website and having images on posts. The images are totally dynamic. Every time a user visits, the images keep changing. So, when a user shares the post on facebook, the og image shows cached image. Is there any way to fetch new data from url and clear the cache when a user shares the post?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just do a POST request (with cURL, for example) to the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com

POST Parameters with values:

- id: https://yourdomain.com/xxx (the URL to rescrape)
- scrape: true

Btw, it´s a very bad idea to rescrape whenever someone hits the Page. OG tags are meant to be static.